# Time array from frequency array in FFT using Python

Tags: python, fftw

I have done a Fourier transformation of two signals (in time) $S_1(t),S_2(t)$ using numpy's `fft` which will give me $S_1(f),S_2(f)$. The corresponding frequency grid I get via `fftfreq`. In the frequency space, I then interpolated the two signals to a new grid using `interp1d`. I need to do this to match the two grids of the signals so that I can divide them at the correct frequencies. However, I now want to transform the divided property $S_1(f)/S_2(f)$ back to time space using `ifft`. But: How do I get the new time grid?

Comment: You can probably use the chirp z-transform to directly transform to the frequency grid you need. For a Python implementation, check https://gist.github.com/endolith/2783807

Answer (score 2):

By interpolating in frequency you are extending the length of your signal in time.  You haven't done anything to increase your sampling rate so $\Delta t$ is fixed.  Your new time grid will be of length N+M where N is the original length and M is the number of points added through interpolation.

Are you uniformly interpolating your frequency domain signal or just interpolating at a few points?

Comment: I am uniformly interpolating the frequency grid. The sampling rate is still fixed, even if I change $\Delta f$, the distance between the frequency points, due to the interpolation?

Comment: Yes, the sampling rate $\Delta t$ is fixed, an increase in frequency resolution, that is a smaller $\Delta f$, increases the length of your time-domain signal.  It is common to zero-pad a time-domain signal for improved frequency resolution. To answer your question, your new time grid is t = (N+M-1)*$\Delta t$